# Does popen load whole output into memory or save in a tmp file(in disk)?

Tags: c++, c, memory, pipe, popen

I want to read part of a very very large compressed file(119.2 GiB if decompressed) with this piece of code.

```cpp
FILE* trace_file;
char gunzip_command[1000];
sprintf(gunzip_command, "gunzip -c %s", argv[i]); // argv[i]: file path
trace_file = popen(gunzip_command, "r");
fread(&current_cloudsuite_instr, instr_size, 1, trace_file)
```

Does popen in c load whole output of the command into memory? If it does not, does popen save the the whole output of the command in a tmp file(in disk)? As you can see, the output of decompressing will be too large. Neither memory nor disk can hold it.
I only know that popen creates a pipe.

```
$ xz -l 649.fotonik3d_s-1B.champsimtrace.xz  
Strms  Blocks   Compressed Uncompressed  Ratio  Check   Filename
    1       1     24.1 MiB    119.2 GiB  0.000  CRC64   649.fotonik3d_s-1B.champsimtrace.xz
```

Comment: `popen()` usually won't use a physical file, it represents the output of the executable as buffered stream in the callers space. Buffered means not the whole output will be read into memory.

Comment: When you use `popen(..., "r")` the `popen` function creates a *pipe*, and makes the programs standard output write to the pipe. You then read the output of the commands from the pipe. And pipes are *buffered*, if the buffer is full then all write operations to the pipe will *block*. Which means the running program will pause. In short: Only a very small potion of the uncompressed file will be in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I only know that popen creates a pipe.

There are two implementations of pipes that I know:

On MS-DOS, the whole output was written to disk; reading was then done by reading the file.

It might be that there are still (less-known) modern operating systems that work this way.

However, in most cases, a certain amount of memory is reserved for the pipe.

The `xz` command can write data until that amount of memory is full. If the memory is full, `xz` is stopped until memory becomes available (because the program that called `popen()` reads data).

If the program that called `popen()` reads data from the pipe, data is removed from the memory so `xz` can write more data.

When the program that called `popen()` closes the file handle, writing to the pipe has no more effect; an error message is reported to `xz` ...